# Object or void* equivalent in Ada

Tags: object, procedure, ada

I'm trying to write a version of my C program in Ada. My C function call looks like this:

```c
void convert(const void* in, void* out){
    MyType* convertedIn = (MyType*)in;
    MyType* convertedOut = (MyType*)out;

    //Assignments and operations to translate values across
    //Example
    convertedOut->meters = convertedIn->feet * 0.3048;
}
```

After searching, I was unable to find anything out there about type casting or any form of Object class or void pointer object for Ada. How would I implement a function like this in Ada?

If I can't implement the function in Ada, how would I wrap the c function with Ada?

I'm using Ada95

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/access#Where_is_void.2A.3F

Comment: How is `convert()` going to know the types of its parameters? How is the Ada programmer going to declare them?

Comment: See [*Ada for the C++ or Java Developer: §5.9 Pointers*](http://www.adacore.com/knowledge/technical-papers/ada-for-the-c-or-java-developer/).

Comment: _Why_ does your C program look like that?  That is, why is it using `void*` instead of actual types?  I think I'd want to know the answer before suggesting an Ada solution.  The answer is probably going to be that it would be best to give some thought to the program design before trying to convert to Ada.  In C (as opposed to C++) I guess you sometimes have to use this to work around missing features, but if that's the case, then you may know more about what the program was trying to accomplish, and you should let us know what it is.

Comment: Your function doesn't actually "convert" anything, since both the in and out parameters are `void*`.

Comment: @Patrick how can you tell that without seeing the body of the subroutine?  Maybe it does convert something.  The parameters are apparently cast to pointers to some other type, and then perhaps the data pointed to by the new pointer is converted.  Typical sort of ugly thing you have to do in C.

Comment: @ajb My point is the question is not well-written as-is.  No body is given for convert, so all we can do is guess what @mikeyGlitz is trying to do.  My guess was he's trying to "convert" `in` to `out`, but both are `void*` so the net result is a `NOOP`.

Comment: The void* in and void* out get casted to their expected types and then values from the in get assigned to the out variable:

    void convert(const void* in, void* out){
        MyType* input = (MyType*)in;
        MyType* output = (MyType*)out;
        output->field1 = input->field1;
        ....
    }

I understand that I'm flying pretty loose with the type casting in this example. I omitted a lot of the code that gets called beforehand to resolve which convert function to call (there are multiple that get loaded into the system).

Comment: @mikeyGlitz: Please update your question to reflect this clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```ada
type Example is tagged null record;

procedure Convert (From : in     Example'Class;
                   To   :    out Example'Class) is
begin
   null; --  Implement conversion here
end Convert;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I needed using System.Address and Ada.Unchecked_Conversion. Below is my code:

```ada
with MyPackage;

type MyTypePtr is access MyType;

procedure Convert (From : in     System.Address;
                   To   : out  System.Address) is
   function ConvertAddressToMyType is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(
                        Source => System.Address;
                        Target => MyTypePtr); 
begin
   null; --  Implement conversion here
end Convert;
```

Comment: It's usually considered bad design in Ada to pass around addresses like that. -- I suggest reading this: http://blog.kickin-the-darkness.com/2007/08/fundamental-theory-of-ada.html -- and then considering what you're trying to do in terms of types.