# Import C function with void* parameter

Tags: import, ada, void-pointers

I want to import a C function in Ada.

There is the C part :

```
void Register(const void *ctxt)
{
   saved_ctxt = ctxt; // This is a global variable 
}

void Send_Trace(const void *ctxt,
                const char *msg)
{
    if (saved_ctxt == ctxt)
    {
        // Do stuff with msg
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this function in a Ada program. There is my code :

```
type T_void is tagged null record;
package C renames Interfaces.C;

procedure Send_Trace_From_C(ctxt : in T_void;
                            msg  : in String)
is
    pragma Convention(C, T_void);

    procedure send_trace (A: out T_void; B : C.Strings.char_ptr);
    pragma import (C, Send_Trace, "Send_Trace");

    Char_ptr : C.Strings.char_ptr := C.Strings.New_String(msg);
begin
    send_trace (ctxt, Char_ptr);
end Send_Trace_From_C;
```

But I have errors :

> pragma "convention" argument must be in same declarative part
>
> warning "send_trace" involves a tagged type which does not correspond to any C type

How can I use a *void in Ada ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the convention when you create the type:

```
type Foo is ...
with Convention => C;
```

Why did you make `T_void` a *tagged* record? The compiler can’t export it to C, because the C side wouldn’t understand it, so don’t. A `null record` is eligible for convention C ([ARM B.1(16)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-B-1.html#p16)). As the code stands, it’s very likely to be passed to the C by address ([ARM B.3(69)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-B-3.html#p69)), which is what you want.

The first parameter to `send_trace` should be `in`-mode.

Comment: the `tagegd record` comes from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531895/object-or-void-equivalent-in-ada. But maybe it was not the best way to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

*void ** can be translated to *System.Address* in Ada.

`procedure Register (ctx : System.Address);`

However, using *System.Address* has drawbacks.
For example, the compiler does not check the actual parameter passed to the function is declared aliased.
It is better to declare multiple *Register* functions with a access type as formal parameter and call the C function from there. One function per *ctxt* access type.

```
procedure Register (ctx : System.Address);

procedure Register_Ada (ctx : access Data_Type1);  --  Call Register  from there
procedure Register_Ada (ctx : access Data_Type2);  --  Call Register  from there
procedure Register_Ada (ctx : access Data_Type3);  --  Call Register  from there

Register_ada (Data1'Access);
Register_ada (Data2'Access);
Register_ada (Data3'Access);
```

Or you can declare Unchecked conversions from `access types` to `System.Address` and call `Register` directly :

```
function To_Address is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Source => Data_Type1_Ptr, Target => System.Address);
function To_Address is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Source => Data_Type2_Ptr, Target => System.Address);
function To_Address is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Source => Data_Type3_Ptr, Target => System.Address);

Register (To_Address (Data1'Access));
Register (To_Address (Data2'Access));
Register (To_Address (Data2'Access));
```

Both solutions force the compiler to check that the data are declared aliased.

Comment: This is wrong. `System.Address` is implementation defined, with the advice that "Address should be a private type". There is no guarantee that it corresponds to a C pointer. Whether or not it does may differ between compilers and even between different versions of the same compiler.

Answer (score 0):

C libraries typically use `void*` for one of two things: as a private type or for generic operations that can take an argument of any type.

The first case maps easily onto an Ada package with a private type and operations on that type. The full type of the private type is a convention-C access type (the designated type is irrelevant). The Ada never allocates or dereferences values of the type.

The second case corresponds to an Ada generic. The operations all have mode `in out` parameters of the generic formal type and the imported C subprograms also have mode `in out` parameters of that type. This results in the Ada compiler passing a C pointer to the parameter to the imported subprograms. The actual parameters need not be aliased, and no access types or values are needed on the Ada side.

It looks as if you may be dealing with the generic case, but you have not provided enough information to be sure.

Of course, there are many poorly designed C libraries that use `void*` that don't fall into either of these cases. For such libraries, more effort is required.

Comment: How do you manage this when the function address comes from a dynamic library ?

Comment: I would have to see an example to know what you mean.

Comment: For example, on Windows, after loading a dynamic library with `LoadLibrary()`, one get function addresses with `GetProcAddress()` which returns an address.
How do you get function pointers without using `System.Address` ?

Comment: How is the type of the address that is returned defined?

Comment: This is how to do it :
`function GetProcAddress (hModule : HINSTANCE; lpLibFileName : LPCSTR) return System.Address;
   pragma Import (Stdcall, GetProcAddress, "GetProcAddress");`
Then I assign the address to a function pointer through a Unchecked_Conversion.